# using logstash to transport csv file to server

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm currently learning to use bigdata, 
client side : Windows 10
serverside : CentOS7
the elasticsearch, logstash and kibana have been installed on the serverside,
as a client side i can access kibana by http://10.64.2.246:5601/, everything cool. now i would like to learn how transport data from my pc to elasticsearch on the server side. I've downloaded logstash on the client side.

I've prepared the data from kaggle with 2 columns.
i've made my conf file

## conf file

```
input   {
    file    {
        path => "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\DATA"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path=>"/dev/null"
    }
}
filter  {
    csv     {
        separator=>","
        columns=>["Date","Price"]
    }
    mutate {convert =>["Price","float"]}
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        host => "10.64.2.246"
        index=>"oil"
        document_type=>"minyaks"
    }
    stdout{}
}
```

## here is my code to execute the conf file which i executed on client side.

`bin/logstash -f /Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash_oil.conf`

here is the error that shown

```
Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-11-07T20:33:11,077][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-11-07T20:33:11,090][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.4.2"}
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,416][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 29 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,917][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,925][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:100)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:60)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1143)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)", "C_3a_.Users.Charles.Desktop.DATA.logstash_minus_7_dot_4_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:26)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:91)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:90)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:915)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:183)", "C_3a_.Users.Charles.Desktop.DATA.logstash_minus_7_dot_4_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36)", "C_3a_.Users.Charles.Desktop.DATA.logstash_minus_7_dot_4_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:91)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:90)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:183)", "C_3a_.Users.Charles.Desktop.DATA.logstash_minus_7_dot_4_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:136)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:77)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:129)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:295)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:274)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:270)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"]}
warning: thread "Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`
          create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109
             add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37
  converge_state at C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,932][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>LogStash::Error, :message=>"Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`", :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in `add'", "C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,954][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in `add'", "C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-11-07T20:33:13,004][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

need someone to explain this to me. I follow the instruction from youtube but the instructor do it locally.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```
[2019-11-07T20:33:12,917][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch
```

So you need to change

```
    host => "10.64.2.246"
```

to

```
    hosts => "10.64.2.246"
```

Also, since you appear to be using ES 7.4.2, you can remove the following line as [document/mapping types are deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/removal-of-types.html)

```
document_type=>"minyaks"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply!! i got different following error now, [WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://10.64.2.246:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://10.64.2.246:9200/][Manticore::ConnectTimeout] connect timed out"}

Comment: Yes, that's because 10.x IP addresses are private IPs and you cannot reach them from outside your VPC. You need to either use a public IP address or access your VPC through a bastion host.

Comment: alright, thank you so much for the guides, im still looking for someways to make this happening.

Comment: You don't need logstash in the client side to push logs, you can use Filebeat it needs less resources and it is easier to configure.

Comment: Indeed, since Filebeat 7,2, a new [`decode_csv_fields` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.4/decode-csv-fields.html) is now available. And the `mutate/convert` filter could be achieved with an [ingest `convert` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html)

Comment: I've tried using filebeats following some instructor online but it didnt give me any logs on kibana. I've created another thread with more detailed configuration. please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833999/transport-csv-file-with-filebeat. It really frustrating. Thank you so much.