# Transport csv file with filebeat

Tags: csv, bigdata, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

## Case

push csv file from client PC to elastic on server side

the elastic have been installed, nicely. I can accessed it from my pc and use demo data. Now I would like to learn how to push it with my own data. I've prepared my data from kaggle.

## Client side

I've downloaded filebeat on client side and extracted it. 
i've edited the filebeat.yml as

```
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\DATA\BrentOilPrices.csv
document_type: test_log_csv
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["10.64.2.246:5044"]
```

I also tested it with

```
./filebeat test config
```

it return :
Config Ok

## Server side

edited logstash.conf as

```
input {
beats {
port =>5044
}
}

filter {

if "test_log_csv" in [type]
{
csv {
columns=>["Date","Price"]
separator=>","
}
mutate{
convert => ["Price","integer"]
}
date{
match=>["Date","d/MMM/yy"]
}
}
}

output {
if "test_log_csv" in [type]
{
elasticsearch
{
hosts=>"127.0.0.1:9200"
index=>"test_log_csv%{+d/MM/yy}"
}
}
```

## Client side

I run

```
Start-Service filebeat
```

it returns nothing.

I checked my kibana and there are no logs .
what did i miss?

## Edited filebeat.yml at client side

```
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - 'C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\DATA\BrentOilPrices.csv'
fields:
document_type: test_log_csv
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["10.64.2.246:5044"]
```

Comment: Which version of filbeat are you using? The `document_type` has been removed since version 6.0, it does not work anymore, you need to use the [`fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-fields) option. Also, use forward slashes(`/`) on your path input, even on windows.

Comment: sorry for late reply, im using 7.4.2 filebeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document_type` option was removed from Filebeat in version 6.X so the `type` field is not created anymore, since your conditionals are based on this field, your pipeline will not work. Also, you should try to use forward slashes (`/`) even on windows.

Try to change your config for the one below and test again.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - 'C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/DATA/BrentOilPrices.csv'
fields:
  type: test_log_csv
fields_under_root: true
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["10.64.2.246:5044"]
```

The option `fields_under_root: true` will create the field `type` in the root of your document, if you remove this option, the field will be created as `[fields][type]` and you will need to change your conditionals to that field.

Comment: hi there, thank you so much for replying me. I've followed your instruction, but nothing changes.

Comment: Try to run your logstash pipeline withouth any `if` conditions in filter and in output to see what is being collected.